# ZeroMQ Connector How to check if an order has been closed by SL/TP?

Tags: python, zeromq

There is little information about ZeroMQ Connector, I was following the 7 video tutorials on how to interface python with a MetaTrader Terminal 4 and got no problem running them on iPython kernel just as instructed in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2VdXdm2qlM&t=9s*)

I have an issue is that how to check if an order has been closed by SL/TP, I am thinking one way is to get the comment as after TP or SL, in the comment, it has[tp] for example:

```
EURUSD_Trader[tp]
```

Can anyone share some sample codes that I can access that to check if an order has been closed by SL/TP. I assume others may have the same problem, so I post it here.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the MT4 server itself appends the comment with the reason; alternatively, the DWX API appears to support looking up the order's TP/SL values directly, so you could compare those with the closing price and determine whether one was triggered (within the slippage threshold, I guess)

Comment: How can I grab the latest closded order to grab the comment, may you provide the sample code